# "Shutdown settings" in Power Options are missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-management, control-panel

Windows should have such a menu in Control Panel's Power Options:
[image: Settings available]

But I don't have it:
[image: Settings unavailable]

I use Windows 10 Home

Comment: Your are not on the same page. You are editing a power plan, while the reference screenshot is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first image didn't come from Windows 10.

To reach these settings in Windows 10, go to
*Start > Power Options > Change plan settings >
Choose what the power buttons do*.

The settings will be disabled by default. To enable, click
"Change settings that are currently unavailable".

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thank you!